# SwipeRefreshLayout with multiple ListViews

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a pretty complicated structure with a `FrameLayout` containing 2 `LinearLayout`s (one is only shown at a time).

One of the `LinearLayout`s needs a pull-to-refresh.

So my layout XML looks kind of like this:

```
<FrameLayout>
    [...]
    <SwipeRefreshLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
            <TextView/>
            <TextView/>
            <ListView/>
            <TextView/>
            <ListView/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </SwipeRefreshLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I want to be able to pull-to-refresh on the whole `Linearlayout`, that's why my idea was to wrap it all with the `SwipeRefreshLayout`. But pulling on `TextView`s does not work now and sometimes the behavior is really weird (I see the bubble but it disappears immediately).

Only if I pull on one of the `ListView`s, the thing works as intended.

I even tried importing the `MultiSwiperefreshLayout` (from [here](https://developer.android.com/samples/SwipeRefreshMultipleViews/src/com.example.android.swiperefreshmultipleviews/MultiSwipeRefreshLayout.html)) and setting:

```
swipeLayout.setSwipeableChildren(R.id.xxx); // Id of my linearlayout
```

Do you have any idea how to make a `Refreshlayout` wrap a complex layout like mine and work properly there?

Comment: Your title says "with mutiple ListViews" but it looks like it should be "with multiple LinearLayouts" or "with multiple SwipeRefreshLayout", isn't?

Comment: So i have multiple Listviews in one container where swiperefreshlayout is to be shown.
I also have multiple linearlayouts, but only on one of them swiperefreshlayout will be used  --> one linearlayout with 2 listviews wrapped inside swiperefreshlayout

Comment: This is known to be conflicting. I have the same problem and ended up revamping my UI... I'll upvote to see if anyone got something good about this :)

Comment: It is generally bad idea to put `ListView` into other scrollable view and you put two. Is there some reason to do that? I think you would solve the problem by fixing that..

Comment: I need two different listviews on one screen because i show a list of done things and a list of todo things in separate lists

Comment: @shkschneider how did you revamp the ui? Got rid of multiple lists?

Comment: @maksim Kinda had to (I splitted my UI). Maybe a solution exists now that I'm not aware.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it！
I meet the same problem, and solved it.
My problem below:

```
<MultiSwipeRefreshLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <ListView  @+id/list_1 />
            <TextView  @+id/list_1_empty_view />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout>
            <ListView  @+id/list_2 />
            <TextView  @+id/list_2_empty_view />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</MultiSwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and I resolve it reference: https://developer.android.com/samples/SwipeRefreshMultipleViews/index.html

Behind this example`s thought,I rewrite the SwipeRefreshLayout with a lit difference.

1)Firstly, I new a MultiSwipeRefreshLayout.java class, because my modificine, I have to do this other than extend SwipeRefreshLayout class;

2)Secondly, I copy all content of SwipeRefreshLayout.java to MultiSwipeRefreshLayout.java, and add these code below:

```
private View[] mSwipeableChildren;

/**
 * 记录子视图中是否有控件可以上滑的；该值在每次的ACTION_DOWN时计算一次。
 */
private boolean canChildScrollUp = true;
/**
 * Set the children which can trigger a refresh by swiping down when they are visible. These
 * views need to be a descendant of this view.
 */
public void setSwipeableChildren(final int... ids) {
    assert ids != null;

    // Iterate through the ids and find the Views
    mSwipeableChildren = new View[ids.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        mSwipeableChildren[i] = findViewById(ids[i]);
    }
}
/**
 * This method controls when the swipe-to-refresh gesture is triggered. By returning false here
 * we are signifying that the view is in a state where a refresh gesture can start.
 *
 * <p>As {@link android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout} only supports one direct child by
 * default, we need to manually iterate through our swipeable children to see if any are in a
 * state to trigger the gesture. If so we return false to start the gesture.
 */
public boolean canChildScrollUp(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (mSwipeableChildren != null && mSwipeableChildren.length > 0
            && ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // Iterate through the scrollable children and check if any of them can not scroll up
        // 找到那个能接受到 ev 的控件
        View target = null;
        for (View view : mSwipeableChildren) {
            if (view != null && view.isShown() && isInViewRect(ev, view)) {
                target = view;
            }
        }

        // 当前接受滑动事件的ListView是否可以向上滑动
        if (target != null && canViewScrollUp(target) ) {
            canChildScrollUp = true;
        }else{
            canChildScrollUp = false;
        }
    }
    return canChildScrollUp;
}

/**
 * 判断点击事件是否在目标控件内
 * @param ev
 * @param view
 * @return
 */
private static boolean isInViewRect(MotionEvent ev, View view){
    //计算View的坐标
    int location[] = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    RectF viewRectF = new RectF(
            location[0], location[1],
            location[0]+view.getWidth(), location[1] + view.getHeight()
    );

    float xOnScreen = ev.getRawX();
    float yOnScreen = ev.getRawY();

    return viewRectF.contains(xOnScreen, yOnScreen);
}

/**
 * Utility method to check whether a {@link View} can scroll up from it's current position.
 * Handles platform version differences, providing backwards compatible functionality where
 * needed.
 */
private static boolean canViewScrollUp(View view) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        // For ICS and above we can call canScrollVertically() to determine this
        return ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(view, -1);
    } else {
        if (view instanceof AbsListView) {
            // Pre-ICS we need to manually check the first visible item and the child view's top
            // value
            final AbsListView listView = (AbsListView) view;
            return listView.getChildCount() > 0 &&
                    (listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() > 0
                            || listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() < listView.getPaddingTop());
        } else {
            // For all other view types we just check the getScrollY() value
            return view.getScrollY() > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

change original method :canChildScrollUp() ->> canChildScrollUp(MotionEvent ev),
and add a field:canChildScrollUp. The rest is same with google sammple inside above refrence.

OK,then we can add multi ListView or ScrollView or TextView or other widget.I mean we can contains more than one ListView in a SwipeRefreshLayout.

I`m chinese, so forgive my english level for god's sake.